# sql join with conditions when creating columns with arithmetic operators

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join tables together while creating new columns that depend on the values of different tables in the join. This obviously doesn't work but hopefully illustrates what I'd like to accomplish:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, 
   (b.column1*2 IF a.column1 > 1 ELSE b.column1*.5) as adj_b1
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b
ON a.3 = b.3
LEFT OUTER JOIN c
ON a.3 = c.3
```

I stumbled upon the IF syntax and my best attempt was creating a select statement along these lines:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, ((SELECT IF(a.column1 > 1, b.column1*2, b.column1*.5) FROM a, b AS adj_b1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to handle Null values ;).

Comment: What does it mean it doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the code gives me an error (error code: 1064) when I attempt to create the new columns in the join. If I just wanted to join the tables, I'd be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be handled using a simple [CASE](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/case.php) Statement like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN a.column1 > 1 
            THEN COALESCE(b.column1,0)*2
         ELSE COALESCE(b.column1,0)*5 
       END as adj_b1, 
       a.*, 
       b.*, 
       c.* 
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b
ON a.3 = b.3
LEFT OUTER JOIN c
ON a.3 = c.3;
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `CASE` usually does the job . Let me know if it works for you .

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN a.column1 > 1 THEN
               COALESCE(b.column1,0)*2
               ELSE COALESCE(b.column1,0)*5 
       END as adj_b1, a.*, b.*, c.* 
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b
ON a.3 = b.3
LEFT OUTER JOIN c
ON a.3 = c.3
```

Comment: There are 2 functions replacing your null values .Try it like that.